# How to draw a line in Tkinter with n segments?

Tags: python, tkinter, line, shapes

I'd like to draw lines with an n number or segments [as such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYbqq.png) (this is a line with 5 segments).

Here is what I have:

```
def connect_nodes(node, node_to_connect, segments, color, canvas):
    canvas.create_line(node[0], node[1], node_to_connect[0], node_to_connect[1], fill=color)
```

This draws a straight line without any segments. Is there a way to segment the line such that it has `segments` number of segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dash=(pixels_to_draw, gap_in_pix)`(eg: `dash=(5, 1)`) option of `create_line` will not give you control over how many segments a line could be broken into.

If you want to break a line into specified segments, you will have to draw multiple lines, and if you want to modify the line give it the same tag.

Here is an example.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import math


def create_segmented_line(x, y, x1, y1, number_of_seg: int, gap: int, *args, **kwargs):

    line_length = math.sqrt((x1 - x)**2 + (y1 - y)**2)

    seg = line_length / number_of_seg 

    n_x, n_y = (x1-x) / line_length, (y1-y) / line_length

    _x, _y = x, y
    dist = seg - gap/2
  
    tag = f"segment{id(seg)}" # keep tag unique for each segment

    for s in range(number_of_seg): 

        canvas.create_line(_x, _y, ((dist - gap/2)*n_x) + x, ((dist - gap/2)*n_y) + y, tags=tag, *args, **kwargs)
        _x, _y = ((dist + gap/2)*n_x) + x, ((dist + gap/2)*n_y) + y
        dist += seg

    return tag

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="white")
canvas.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

x, y, x1, y1 = 50, 100, 150, 150

create_segmented_line(x, y, x1, y1, 5, 2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @CairoMisr can you post your code on pastebin and paste the link here?

Comment: Here, I don't know what is wrong, but I tested your code separately and it works. https://pastebin.com/sm0g56d5

Comment: @CairoMisr you seem to have removed the `x, y, x1, y1, number_of_seg: int, gap: int` parameters without actually modifying the function definition. If you are removing the parameters you will have to modify it also in the function definition. Besides this, I also believe that the canvas should be a global variable in your code.

Comment: When used multiple times, the position of the line deviates. Try running this: https://pastebin.com/dL8ViwFi

Comment: @CairoMisr btw, are you trying to implement something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68949334/15993687)

Comment: Not exactly but the idea is similar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238110/discussion-between-cairomisr-and-art).

Comment: This does not work with large x and y values due to the fact that the line deviates when doing so

Comment: @CairoMisr sorry, my bad try the new one. This will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in `canvas.create_line` called `dash`. For example :

```py
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
f = tkinter.Canvas(root,height = 200,width = 200)

f.create_line(0,0,200,200,dash=10)
f.pack()
root.mainloop()
```